# How to count rows in pandas DF on condition, if column value is a list of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, slice

There is a DF with column Views, which contains lists of dates. I need to count not-empty rows of this DF, i.e. rows where Views != [1970-01-01 00:00:00] (type: list of datetimes)

[image: DF Example]

What I tried:

```
a = datetime.strptime('1970-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
result.loc[result.Views[0] != a ]
result.loc[result.Views[0][0] != a ]
result.loc[result.Views[0][0] != [a] ]
result.loc[result.Views[0] != [a] ]
```

also tried isin, unique funcs, but all it gives  either KeyValue error or 'list not hashable' error

Please, help

UPDATE

The code that works:

```
a = datetime.strptime('1970-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
test = result.explode('Views')
out = test[test.Views != a]
result['Count'] = result.Views.apply(lambda x: sum(y != a for y in x))
viewed = len(result.loc[result.Count > 0]) #Total rows with not empty views
```

But I suspect there is a simpler and quicker way to count such stuff. And nevertheless, how can I achieve items in lists by their index, if this list is a value in DF? - still unanswered

UPDATE

Shortest solution:

```
print(len(df.loc[df["Views"].apply(lambda l: pd.Series(l).explode().ne("1970-01-01").all())]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- given your embedded list is always one row long
- `explode()` and logical operator as mask
- filter and len

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ObjectClass": np.repeat("flats", 20),
        "Views": [
            np.random.choice([pd.to_datetime("1-jan-1970")]+list(pd.date_range("1-aug-2021", periods=3)), random.randint(1,3)) for i in range(20)
        ],
    }
)

print(len(df.loc[df["Views"].apply(lambda l: pd.Series(l).explode().ne("1970-01-01").all())]))
df
```

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot I attached to the answer, the list of views can contain multiple items. Your formula give the following error: raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: ok - updated.  always best to include your data as text / code in a question not an image so answers can use your data

Comment: Now it works as expected, many thanks! I'll include text data next time.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for convert lists to scalars - flatten, so possible compare:

```
df = result.explode('Views')
a = datetime.strptime('1970-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
out = df[df.Views != a ]
```

If need count values use generator with `sum`:

```
result['count'] = result.Views.apply(lambda x: sum(y != a for y in x))
```

Comment: Wow! It Worked! Thanks so much! I'm gonna read now more about the func .explode(). Again many thanks

Comment: I can't count the rows:  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: @Laurel - sorry, answer was changed.

Comment: Your formula now counts total views in each DF row and writes it in a separate column. Now I can count rows with 'count' > 0 and it will give me the desired result, It works ok, but is there a simpler and shorter way?

Comment: @Laurel - Use `result.Views.apply(lambda x: any(y != a for y in x)).sum()`

Comment: @Laurel - check if at least one value match in `any` and then count `True`s by `sum`